# how to add additional text on type

Tags: angular

Below I have an input field, I want to add sf text next to an input , so for example user input 1500 then it will show on the textfield 1500 sf ..but when I submit the SF should not be included.

Any idea would be appreciated , thanks.

#html code

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-32per">
                  <mat-label [ngClass]="{'alter-text-color':dealDispositionFormFields.isSubtenantTakingFullSpace === 'No'}">Subtenant Area (*)</mat-label>                  <input 
                    name = "subTenantArea" 
                    class="alter-text-color"
                    matInput
                    [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.subTenantArea"       
                    [disabled]="dealDispositionFormFields.isSubtenantTakingFullSpace === 'Yes'"              
                    [required]="isExistingDeal">
                </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [`matSuffix`](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples#input-prefix-suffix). This is something that I would use for your scenario:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-32per">
  <mat-label [ngClass]="{'alter-text-color':dealDispositionFormFields.isSubtenantTakingFullSpace === 'No'}">Subtenant Area (*)</mat-label>
  <input name = "subTenantArea" 
         class="alter-text-color"
         matInput
         [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.subTenantArea"
         [disabled]="dealDispositionFormFields.isSubtenantTakingFullSpace === 'Yes'"              
          [required]="isExistingDeal">
  <span matSuffix>sf</span>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Hi , why is that the sf is way too far from the input ? https://imgur.com/a/H84qx1l

Comment: It is supposed to be at the end of the input, because it is a suffix. If you would like it closer to the left side, try replacing the `matSuffix` with `matPrefix` instead, but that will stay in front of the text, not after.

Comment: how to change it so that it will be the same on the screenshot Sir ? can it be possible with css